# how can I animate an element and don't continue till it finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to animate element during a game of cards, but the problem is that when I use the animate function the code is continue to run.
I tried with the `promise()` and `done()` function, but for some reason it doesn't help.

Here is what I did:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".demoCard").animate({
        "margin-top": '-150'
    }, 1000, "easeInSine", function() {
        $(".demoCard").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: And where is the example of the code that continues to run?

Comment: Quit and dirty, if by _"continue to run"_ you mean all other events, make a flag, put a check of the flag in every event, if flag is 1 just return, otherwise continue. when starting to animate set flag to 1, then set flag to 0 in done function

Comment: Actually it's a good idea, I'll try it. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the api documentation. Your callback is correct. Try updating your jQuery api. Maybe you are using an outdated version. If that doesn't work, try removing your easing argument. JQuery might be trying to use the easing argument as a callback function. If you need your easing, make sure you have jQuery UI installed and loaded. Otherwise, jQuery won't recognize the easing, and try to use `easeInOutSine` as the callback function.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. but the problem is that after I do this code the parent element of the (".demoCard") is being deleted, and I need to "freeze" the code till it finish its animate (there is more code after this that I can't use all of it in the callback- I think..)

Comment: I see what you mean. I've had that same problem. The only solution is to use callback. Maybe you can just point function into the callback that has the rest of the code? That would be your best solution.